# GNU G++/Code-Blocks Compiles code but will not run through Code-Blocks or CMD

Tags: c++, gcc, cmd, compiler-errors, codeblocks

So I recently purchased a book about the basics of C++ by SamsTeachYourself.  Great book with great examples but I am having trouble getting any results for any of my code.  I am not sure if I installed the IDE's/compilers wrong but here is what I have:

-GNU g++ compiler/linker
-Code-blocks IDE (dont really use)

and the code I have is an example from the book:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Solidum petit in profundis!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Both my g++ compiler and the IDE compiler will compile this correctly and fast, but when i try to run my program through either the command prompt or IDE, it just shows up with the slow flashing "_", and will not allow me to press any keys and I have to close out of the CMD with the X.  I really could not find answers for this at all anywhere because I dont know whether if its something wrong with my computer, compiler, or code.  Please give your input, all is helpful.  Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Something that simple fixed it. is there something avast does to exe files or cmd prompts?

Comment: Yes, it's an old known problem with avast.